# AWS DynamoDB tutorial does not import certain classes

Tags: android, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to follow a tutorial for DynamoDB on AWS website : http://aws.amazon.com/articles/7439603059327617
I downloaded the file, imported it to Eclipse, imported all the necessary libraries (or literally, all the libraries that came with the github file), but DynamoDBManager.java would keep giving me the dreaded "The import com.amazon... cannot be resolved" error for the following lines:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBScanExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PaginatedScanList;
```

But library is imported for all other classes such as

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DeleteTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DescribeTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DescribeTableResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;
```

Did anyone else run into a similar problem? Could you please direct me in a right direction?!

Thank you in advance & for reading!

Comment: Can you include the jars you have added to your project?  You should only need to include the debug jar for testing purposes.  You can read about the various JARs included in the SDK in [our blog](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3JXN6FGS5Y2L1/Understanding-the-JARs-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android).

Comment: @BobKinney I did indeed try importing debug jar file... but did not work... I just think that the tutorial is outdate haha thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar issue while following a related tutorial
http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1U4RV2QI1MVWS/Amazon-DynamoDB-on-Mobile-Part-1-Loading-Data
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBMapper_UserPreference

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio (0.8.1) and AWS SDK for Android (1.7.1.1). It looks like you're using the wrong package path.

For

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBScanExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PaginatedScanList;
```

you're using `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv.model` when it should be `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling`. For more proof/documentation about the packages you can look at dynmodbv2 [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/package-summary.html) to see that **they are not deprecated**. Change your package path to reflect this:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBScanExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedScanList;
```

and you should hopefully only need to use one of the following:

- aws-android-sdk-VERSION.jar. Contains all necessary files (including
  third-party dependencies) for all supported AWS services. All class
  files were compiled without the debug option.
- aws-android-sdk-VERSION-debug.jar. Contains all files (including third-party dependencies) necessary for debugging. The code was compiled with the debug option on with all symbols retained.

For more on the jars in the AWS SDK for Android see the official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/gsg/Welcome.html)

### Other Potential Issues

(Should only be relevant for AWS SDK for 1.7.1.1 and below if the bug doesn't get fixed in the next rev)

My issue was different in that even though I had the correct package path as per documentation, Android Studio's Intellij couldn't find `dynamodbv2.datamodeling` that is, when typing `import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.` it didn't suggest datamodeling, only utility and model. Trying `import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.*` didn't fix the issue either. Because of this it seems that the datamodeling package isn't wrapped into the two above mentioned packages which in theory are supposed to be all encompassing. To get datamodeling and fix the issue I had in regards to the same objects not being found (DynamoDBAttribute, DynamoDBHashKey, etc.) I had to add as library/file dependencies `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-ddb-mapper.jar` and `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-ddb.jar` and cleaned my project at which point Intellij could see datamodeling when typing import and the sample project could compile.

I imagine you know how to import libraries in your platform as you mentioned importing, but make sure it's only the individual files you need and you don't include `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-debug.jar` or `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1.jar` with them. So for example, my Android Studio module gradle build file dependencies looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-ddb-mapper.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-ddb.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-autoscaling.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-cloudwatch.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-core.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-ec2.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-elb.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-s3.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-sdb.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-ses.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-sns.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-sqs.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-sts.jar')
}
```

The issue I had seems to be a bug where ddb and ddb-mapper weren't included in what should be the all encompassing `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-debug.jar` and `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1.jar`. As such, I have reported on GitHub (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/18) and hopefully the next rev will fix this issue and it will no longer be relevant and you should only need `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-debug.jar` or `aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1.jar`

Comment: happened to stumble across this question after a year, changed the answer to a correct once ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but after digging the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/), it seems like the classes that cannot be resolved are deprecated and are no longer included in the jar files...
They do still exist in the source code folder, but seeing that since they are deprecared, I guess there is no use trying to follow the tutorial...

Comment: This answer is wrong. The files in question are not deprecated. You looked at the wrong documentation. You looked at `com.amazonaws.services.**dynamodb**.datamodeling` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBTable.html)
instead of `com.amazonaws.services.**dynamodb2**.datamodeling`  
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTable.html) which is the package you used (dynamodb2). I'm posting my solution right now as I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamo DB made many breaking changes (requires code change) when they moved to DynamoDB V2.

You need to ensure that the latest SDK is installed and you re using it - In eclipse, you need to also mention which AWS SDK to use (point it to the latest). Though eclipse AWS plugin downloads the latest SDK automatically, it doesnt update the version number to us the latest. You need to update this yourself.

Comment: hmm but even if I do have the latest SDK installed and updated, if the libraries are deprecated, the tutorial would not work right?

Comment: That is also possible if the tutorial was written for the older version.

Answer (score 0):

It is written in AWS Documentation what to do:

> Existing Application
>    The samples included with the AWS SDK for Android are provided as standalone projects set up for you to try out. To use AWS with an existing application, follow these steps:

1. Create a libs directory within your Android project directory if one does not already exist.
2. Copy either a bundled JAR for all services or the specific JARs for the services you wish to use.You have 3 options: Add aws-android-sdk-VERSION-debug.jar. This JAR creates the largest APK, but allows for full stack traces during development. Add aws-android-sdk-VERSION.jar. This JAR creates a smaller APK and a simple bundle when releasing your application. Add the aws-android-sdk-VERSION-core.jar plus the JARs for the individual services your project will use. This method creates the smallest APK, but requires a more complicated setup. Note, copying both bundled JARs and service JARs will cause errors.
3. In Eclipse, go to your project, select Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries and click Add JARs. Then select the JARs you added to your libs directory.