# error: package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 does not exist?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

I am trying to import [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBMapper_UserPreference_Cognito][1]).
in Android Studio .

I am getting error :

```
Error:(21, 41) error: package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2 does not exist ?
```

I have take a reference with this [AWS DynamoDB tutorial does not import certain classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933724/aws-dynamodb-tutorial-does-not-import-certain-classes)  question.

but it not solve my problem .

My screen look like this it will help you to understand my Project structure.

[image]

and the **build.gradel**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amazonaws.demo.userpreferencesom"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
        compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
        compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    }}
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will also need

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-ddb
and
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper

Sorry for the confusion, I will update the readme